# How do we set cursor batch size of posgresql in gorm in golang

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have very large table and where I am doing a `select *` operation in gorm. To improve the performance I would like to set the batch size of the cursor (memory is not a constraint here so I can set it to a large number).
Problem is I am not able to find a way to do this in go-lang using gorm. I have searched through all the documentation I could find.

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Limit-amp-Offset